# Firestore order of ORDER, LIMIT, WHERE clauses

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

Assume we have a dataset like this:

| Name | Population | Capital |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | 8,799,800 | true |
| Barcelona | 1,620,343 | false |
| Luxembourg City | 128,512 | true |

When working with SQL databases, the order in which you typed your ORDER, LIMIT and WHERE clauses is important. For instance:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cities
WHERE Capital = true
ORDER BY Population DESC
LIMIT 2
```

would return London and Luxembourg City. Whereas

```
SELECT *
FROM Cities
ORDER BY Population DESC
LIMIT 2
WHERE Capital = true
```

would return London

(the second statement is probably illegal but that's a different thing)

In Firestore (I'm using the [C# SDK](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries)), we can set the query arguments and then get the snapshot. We could do:

```
Query query = citiesRef
  .WhereEqualTo("Capital", true)
  .OrderByDescending("Population")
  .Limit(2);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

We could also run this:

```
Query query = citiesRef
  .OrderByDescending("Population")
  .Limit(2)
  .WhereEqualTo("Capital", true);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.GetSnapshotAsync();
```

If Firestore was to behave in the way that a SQL database does, these 2 statements would potentially return different results. However, when we run them, they seem to return the same results.

Are the two Firestore queries equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same.  When you specify a limit, you are always limiting the **final** set of results, after all filters and orders, that would be returned to the client so that the results can be [paginated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) by the client.  It is never limiting the data set before any other operations are applied.